# set dropdownlist value to textbox in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

If my dropdown has a value selected, I want to show the selected item text in my textbox. If not, I want to empty it.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddl"  runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" onselectedindexchanged="ddlSelectedIndexChanged" Width="200px" onchange="ddlChange()">
</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:TextBox ID="hdntxtbxTaksit" runat="server" Visible="false"></asp:TextBox>
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using jQuery;

```
$().ready(function(){           
  $('#<%=ddl.ClientID %>').change(function () {               
    $('#<%=hdntxtbxTaksit.ClientID %>').val($(this).val() == "0" ? "" : $(this).val());              
  });
});
```

**EDIT:** With above method, you don't need to call `onchange` event of the dropdown. So your markup can be

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddl"  runat="server" AutoPostBack="true"
         onselectedindexchanged="ddlSelectedIndexChanged" Width="200px">
</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:TextBox ID="hdntxtbxTaksit" runat="server" Visible="false"></asp:TextBox>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to assign selected value of dropdownlist to text box you can assign in change event without and condition as `change event means dropdown have been selected`.

**With javascript**

Change

```
onchange="ddlChange()"
```

To

```
onchange="ddlChange(this)"
```

Your javascrpt method would be

```
function ddlChange(ddl)
{      
      document.getElementById('<%= hdntxtbxTaksit.ClientId %>').value = this.value;
}
```

**With jQuery**

Remove  onchange="ddlChange()" as we will bind event with jquery.

```
$('<%= ddl.ClientId %>').change(function(){          
          $('<%= hdntxtbxTaksit.ClientId %>').val($(this).val());    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like this

```
function ddlChange()
{
   if(document.getElementById('<%= ddl.ClientId %>').value=='0')
   {
      document.getElementById('<%= hdntxtbxTaksit.ClientId %>').value = "";
   }
   else
   {
      document.getElementById('<%= hdntxtbxTaksit.ClientId %>').value = document.getElementById('<%= ddl.ClientId %>').value;    
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code and remove onchange event added in your asp:dropdownlist

**Note:** AUTOPOSTBACK property will always do a page submit, it wont stop even if you return false in onchange method of dropdown

```
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#<%=ddl.ClientID %>').change(function () {

                if ($(this).val() != "0") {
                    $('#<%= hdntxtbxTaksit.ClientID %>').val($(this).val());
                }
                else {
                    $('#<%= hdntxtbxTaksit.ClientID %>').val("");
                }
            });

        });
```