# Having trouble changing field information based on Dropdown list

Tags: c#, drop-down-menu, selectedindexchanged

I think this issue has a simple solution but I have been banging my head on it for a few days now. I have a web application in which Dynamically gets a list of students from a stored procedure. I want to look at detailed information for each student and subsequent class information. On the Student's Details page, there is a dropdown list that contains all the classes that the student is in and when one is selected, the Community Partner field should be updated.

I am using SelectedIndexChanged method but in order to make it work, I need to set AutoPostBack to True and that causes the page to reload and thus the dropdown list and selected value to reload as well. I have tried several different configurations of this code with no results.

Here is my ascx file

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="StudentCourses" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
```

And here is my ascx.cs file

```
protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Session["StudentID"] != null)
        {

            int studentId = Convert.ToInt32(Session["StudentID"]);

            Student student = studentRepository.GetStudent(studentId);
            StudentCourses_SelectedIndexChanged(sender, e);
            StudentCommunityPartner.Text = StudentCourses.SelectedItem.Value;
                ...
```

And here is my SelectedIndexChanged method

```
protected void StudentCourses_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        IList<KeyValuePair<Course, CommunityPartner>> courseList = studentRepository.GetStudentCourses(Convert.ToInt32(Session["StudentID"]));
        StudentCourses.DataSource = courseList;
        StudentCourses.DataBind();

        int ctr = 0;
        foreach (KeyValuePair<Course, CommunityPartner> kvp in courseList)
        {
            if (ctr < StudentCourses.Items.Count)
            {
                StudentCourses.Items[ctr].Text = kvp.Key.CourseCode;
                StudentCourses.Items[ctr].Value = kvp.Value.PartnerName;
                ctr++;
            }
            else ctr = 0;
        }
        StudentCommunityPartner.Text = StudentCourses.SelectedItem.Value;
    }
```

I have tried several combinations and I am at a loss as to how to properly change the content on the page without the dropdownlist refreshing every time I do. Thanks for your help, it is much appreciated.

Comment: "I have tried several combinations and I am at a loss as to how to resolve this issue." ... you never actually state what the issue is

Comment: Just to take a random stab it, I'm guessing in your page_load handler you aren't checking if Page.IsPostBack, and your dropdownlist is getting repopulated with data, which resets its "selected index"

Answer (score 0):

To set a textbox off of a drop down change look here:

[set dropdownlist value to textbox in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13451545/set-dropdownlist-value-to-textbox-in-jquery)

If you have more that you want to do, the selected value from the drop down should be kept in the view state on post back.  You might try saving that value

var Selected = StudentCourses.SelectedValue;

populate the drop down
and then set the selected value with the saved value

StudentCourses.SelectedValue = Selected;